# unity 3d the jump is very short

Tags: unity-game-engine

when my pnj is running(with the right key pressed) and y tried jump the pnj jump. but little very, how could i solucionate this?

This is no a problem when i let to press the right button, but i want make a game without fails and i want jump while io am running, thanks¡

```
 void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            if (corriendo) {
                if (enSuelo || !dobleSalto) {
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x, 0);
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * fuerzaSalto);﻿
                    if (!dobleSalto && !enSuelo){
                        dobleSalto=true;
                    }
                }
                corriendo = true;
            }
        }

        if ((enSuelo || !dobleSalto) && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x, 0);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * fuerzaSalto);﻿
            if (!dobleSalto && !enSuelo){
                dobleSalto=true;
            }
        } 

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) && enSuelo==true) {
            if (velocidad > 17) {
                velocidad = 17;
            }

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x, 0);
            GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector2.right * velocidad);
            velocidad++;
        } else {
            if (velocidad > 1) {
                velocidad--;
            } else {
                velocidad = 0;
            }

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an extra variable in AddForce(Vector2.right * velocidad * jumpFactor)

There you can give to increFactor a value, so you can modify the length of the jump.